# Analyzing network traffic

Tags: networking, tcp

I want to get a good overview what kind of network communication is going on on my computer.

One way would be starting `wireshark`, which is fine for very low-level problems but is quite cumbersome to get a more high level overview.

Usually most packages belong to some TCP stream. And many TCP streams contain some kind of HTTP traffic.

I am looking for some tool like `wireshark` which shows TCP streams just as one line per TCP stream, potentially allowing me to get details about the stream.

Showing HTTP request in a more friendly way would be nice and additionally showing non-TCP traffic, would be nice, too.

Are you aware of some tool like that?

Comment: There is also `ettercap` which shows TCP streams as single line, but it does not show anything else and has a different intend.

Comment: have you tried bandwidthd, it can display in separate HTTP, TCP, UDP traffic

Answer (score 1):

#### ntop

I think the tool you're looking for is [`ntop`](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/).

> ntopng is the next generation version of the original ntop, a network traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does. ntopng is based on libpcap and it has been written in a portable way in order to virtually run on every Unix platform, MacOSX and on Win32 as well.
>
> ntopng users can use a a web browser to navigate through ntop (that acts as a web server) traffic information and get a dump of the network status. In the latter case, ntopng can be seen as a simple RMON-like agent with an embedded web interface. The use of:
>
> - a web interface.
> - limited configuration and administration via the web interface.
> - reduced CPU and memory usage (they vary according to network size and traffic).

#### screenshot

[image: ss #1]

#### iftop

As an alternative that runs in a terminal you could also try using `iftop`.

```
$ sudo iftop -i wlp3s0
```

**NOTE:** That's my WiFi network device.

#### screenshot

[image: ss #2]